# Perform vector calculation on GPU in C++, regardless of brand

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, gpgpu

How do I perform a calculation (and assign the result to a variable), regardless of brand (AMD, Nvidia, even an iGPU) on a GPU?

I would like the most simple and efficient API, something where I can just call a function with the input of the calculation and it will calculate it on the GPU, and assign the value to the `float t`.

The calculation is:

```
float t = - (dot(N, orig) + D) / dot(N, dir);
```

...[from here](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution.html#:%7E:text=float%20t%20%3D%20%2D%20(dot(N%2C%20orig)%20%2B%20D)%20/%20dot(N%2C%20dir)%3B).

Comment: Something like [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)?

Comment: @Eljay, Sorry that I wasn't clear in the question, but I don't want a whole language (although it's similar to C++), I just want a API, something where I can just call a function with the input of the calculation and it will calculate it on the GPU, and return the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Took me a bit of Google searching, but eventually I decided on SYCL (oneapi). The installation process was tough, but once I got it working, it was perfect for my application.